# redrawing/refilling jquery datatable data set after page change or any other event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have a jquery datatable in my page which I fill up with data like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datatable;
    $(document).on("click", ".myBtnClass", function () {
        if (datatable != null)
            datatable.destroy();
        datatable = $('#tableProducts').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 50,
            "processing": false,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "orderMulti": false,

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Bulk/LoadData/",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": {
                    "username": $(".sellerInput").val(),
                    "drange": $(".select2").val()
                },
                "dataSrc": function (data) {
                    return data.data;
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

So as you can see here I'm filling up the datatable with data that my method returns "LoadData" ...

The problem here is in this line:

```
if (datatable != null)
        datatable.destroy();
```

Every time I destroy the table in order to recreate it with new data, I loose the design of the table, and it becomes deformed and looks ugly after it's destroyed/recreated....

Is there any other way to reload the data into the table without actually calling the destroy() method ?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Something is missing, how does columns and JSON look like?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for [**datatable.ajax.reload()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) ..?

Answer (score 0):

You could try two different approaches:

**1. Destroy/reinstanciate the table**

add the option `destroy:true` in the table's initialization, and remove

```
 if (datatable != null)
         datatable.destroy();
```

This tells datatables to destroy and reinstanciate the table when you call the initalization function on an existing instance.

However, this might still mess up the table's design.

**2. Use ajax.reload()**

another, perhaps preferable approach, is to reload the data using the url provided in the ajax option:

```
$('#tableProducts').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

[Here's](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) more info about the `ajax.reload()` functionality.